# Is Zend related to PHP just like jQuery is related to javascript?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is the Zend Framework similar in use in relation to PHP just like jQuery is used for javascript?

Comment: This could easily be determined by a quick google search: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework, but yes, Zend Framework is built upon PHP similar to jQuery being built upon JavaScript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only in the sense that thing A is written in thing B and attempts to make doing things C, D, and E easier for programmers using thing B.

Programmers have been writing libraries of code for their favourite language for decades. It's called 'not re-inventing the wheel' and is a Good Thing.

In this case you are talking about two different wheels. On two different types of transportation vehicle.

Answer (score 2):

Zend is an MVC (model view controller) framework that allows you to build applications in php following that particular design pattern.
jQuery is a library that lets you do lot of stuff with the DOM and simplify javascript/DOM/ajax coding.
My answer is no :)

Answer (score 1):

i think Following notes can help you::
Framework is collection of libraries which have software help, Many code libraries,scripting languages, Support programs etc..
But libraries is simple collection Of methods!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. Zend Framework is framework and jQuery is library. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057526/framework-vs-toolkit-vs-library) about difference between framework and library.

Comment: What is the difference? Framework is a set of libraries, and jquery library is a set of plugins. The exactly same things with just different names.

Comment: I was reading one of the other stackoverflow questions similar to mine. So a framework is basically multiple libraries weaved together right? I might be wrong though, I'm a library/framework noob just learning this stuff.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to compare Zend Framework with extjs rather than with jQuery... extjs is a framework for javascript that can (optionally) use the jQuery library

Comment: @Qlidnaque: the terms of plugin, package, library, framework, extension etc are vague, so depending on the case (programming language, programming technique, etc) you can use the different terms.

Comment: @KomarSerjio: also the highest rated answer in the topic you pointed is just incorrect: there is nothing to do with IoC in defining framework. I can use ZF and controll all the process (ie, without zend application structure). Will the ZF be less framework in this case? Obviously - no.

Comment: @KomarSerjio: so what? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057526/framework-vs-toolkit-vs-library --- it is just a **subjective** opinion of one particular person.

Comment: @zerkms Yes, you can use ZF as library (just use some components). But if your app is based on ZF it means that you use framework (framework calls your code).

Comment: @zerkms, there is a difference (in my view): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952974/what-is-the-difference-between-a-class-and-a-library/4953194#4953194

Comment: @KomarSerjio: it is just an opinion. How do you get it is "correct"? Based on what criterias? What framework term description is that answer based on? Is there only one framework term description?

Comment: @ircmaxell: yes, your answer is much better, since it doesn't rely on IoC only. And IoC is not a requirement for some bunch of code to be called a framework.

Comment: Main difference: "You call a library's code. A Framework calls your code." I'm tired to repeat this.

Comment: @KomarSerjio: yes, indeed, and this has nothing to do with IoC. IoC is a technique about how the dependencies are controlled (resolved), not about an application workflow. Even if framework calls your code - it doesn't mean it follows IoC ideas. Is it clear enough?

Comment: @KomarSerjio: yes, it is mine. And yours doesn't correlate with the one you referred to. IoC has nothing to do with workflow. Can't you get the difference between terms DI (and dependencies at all) and application workflow?

Comment: @KomarSerjio: Also, there is no any DI containter in ZF - so ZF is not a framework then?

Comment: @zerkms: I'm not sure that you are familiar with term IoC. Yes, DI is IoC, but IoC is not necessary dependency injection.

Comment: @KomarSerjio: I definitely am familiar with it. IoC is about resolving dependencies. And there is no configurable container in ZF. So ZF is not a framework?

Comment: @zerkms: IoC is abount flow of control, but not just about dependencies. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that jQuery is what CakePHP is for PHP and Zend Framework is what DOJO is for Javascript.

jQuery helps you with simple tasks, but is discutable for enterprise usage for the lack of systematic classes. It's more of the quick 'n dirty solution. It's faster in simple tasks, but for complex application it meets it's boundaries. It lacks comprehensive extensions loading mechanism AFAIK.