# Benefits of using cakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I know PHP well.  But i haven't tried cakePHP before and i was willing to learn cakePHP.  So just want to know that is there any  benefits of using cakePHP over PHP?

Thanks,
  aby

Comment: http://cakephp.org/pages/features

Comment: If you use CakePHP, you are also using PHP. The question needs better wording.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Framework benefits and downfalls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060699/php-framework-benefits-downfalls)

Comment: @Gordon he does specify that he knows PHP well...

Comment: +1 @Gordon, this should be an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[cakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), like [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/), [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com/) and [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) (just to name a few) are frameworks. What this means is that they have tried to abstract some of the normal, every-day things you do in development in an effort to speed up development time and make you more profitable.

In today's world, there is no excuse for not using a framework. If you refuse to use a framework, you find yourself creating a lot of the things that a good framework provides anyway (i.e. data abstraction layers, session classes, form validation, etc). By using a framework, you not only gain time, but you gain stability as the different components of the framework should be designed to work well together and have been thoroughly tested by the community.

Whichever framework you choose is up to you and hopefully now you understand it's benefits.

Comment: -1 a framework is an option and not mandatory at all. PHP provides a good deal of functionality out of the Box (DBA, I10n, …) and there is absolutely no reason to lock into a full stack like Cake, CI or Symfony. If you are looking for components, use a compontent library, like PEAR, ZF or Zeta. Also, the purported time benefits often only apply when you dont have to customize any components. And let's not forget you have to learn a framework too.

Comment: Also be very careful confusing libraries and frameworks.  While all frameworks are libraries, not all libraries are frameworks.  Every single argument you made here are for using libraries.  There is a significant different.

Comment: @ircmaxell - I think you've mentioned 'Using frameworks as libraries' at SO Chat - can you elaborate on it? I'm still confused. How do we use frameworks as libraries? If we use a framework, that would mean we are tied to the way the framework runs things, right? How can we use a framework as a library?

Comment: @rickchristie: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952974/what-is-the-difference-between-a-class-and-a-library/4953194#4953194) for more explanation of the distinction.

Comment: @Gordon - I disagree. If you're creating a simple little script that you're only using for one purpose, by all means don't use a full-fledged framework. However, if you're building any kind of dynamic web app, you should be using a framework. There's no sense in re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: We have to agree to disagree then. Using a framework for the sake of using a framework is naively ignoring the costs of frameworks and the real project requirements. If your non-reinvented wheels are too big or too small for the car or you have a boat, then they wont get you anywhere. A suit that doesnt fit doesnt fulfill it's purpose.

Comment: @Gordon i also have to disagree, today it's almost inconceivable that you'd need to write something from scratch... db interaction? user auth? form validation? routing? caching? .. why would you want to hack any of the above together, even if using different components from various frameworks, when you have very solid options already available.

Comment: @vladko yes, but these solid options don't need to be full stack frameworks of various quality forcing their opinion onto you and your project. It's about making appropriate choices. That choice can be a framework, but it also can be just some lib. And sometimes the choice will be to write something from scratch because existing solutions don't meet your needs or because it's quicker to quickly write that authenticator with PDO over customizing whatever framework X provides.

Comment: @Gordon fair enough, but in the context of the question it may not have been the right comment. There are definite benefits to using a framework, but as you say it may not be the be all end all solution. Quite often one will have to rely on additional components and possibly custom modules to achieve better architecture especially in the enterprise level apps

Answer (score 3):

CakePHP is an [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework that will allow you to setup your data model and connect it to a database to be easily manipulated in PHP. It also allows you separate your business logic from your display logic using a controller.

It also gives you a lot of useful functionality like authorization, sessions, form validation, pagination.. for free. You should check out the [feature list](http://cakephp.org/pages/features).

If you didn't use CakePHP you would have to roll your own framework, which is a lot of extra hassle and work. There are of course other frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is pretty simple, it comes down to your need's, do you need a framework?

You say that you know php well, i doubt you know it as well as you think as you would not ask a question of this nature, you would understand the concepts behind a framework.

You say:

> So just want to know that is there any benefits of using cakePHP over PHP?

it's not a language sir, it's a framework that supplies the PHP foundations for an application, why would you not wan't to use such a thing, what you should be asking is:

> What's the best framework to learn once you have mastered PHP Fundamentals.

But don't ask it here, there are plenty of posts that answer that question for you.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP is an MVC framework But to simply say you need to design the data models and relationship (creating necessary tables) before start the work , once you use bake command 70% of coding are given